# Why is there currently no bitcoin package in Debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Why is the `bitcoin` package currently not in Debian? And how to help get it back in there?

It'd make it a lot easier for more people to run a full node with this.

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/bitcoin

[image: bitcoin REMOVED from testing]

Answer (score 1):

> Why is there currently no bitcoin package in Debian?

Your link also says:

> ### action needed
>
> ```
> Problems while searching for a new upstream version                  high  
> 2 security issues in sid                                             high  
> Depends on packages which need a new maintainer                      normal  
> The package has not entered testing even though the delay is over    normal  
> Build log checks report 1 warning                                    low  
> Standards version of the package is outdated.                        wishlist
> ```
>
> ### testing migrations
>
> excuses:
>
> - Migration status for bitcoin (- to 0.18.1~dfsg-1): BLOCKED:  Rejected/violates migration policy/introduces a regression
> - Issues preventing migration:
> - Updating bitcoin introduces new bugs: #939608
> - Additional info:
> - Piuparts tested OK - https://piuparts.debian.org/sid/source/b/bitcoin.html
> - 241 days old (needed 5 days)
> - Not considered

If you drill into the details you find security bugs such as [CVE-2019-15947](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2019-15947)

> In Bitcoin Core 0.18.0, bitcoin-qt stores wallet.dat data unencrypted in memory. Upon a crash, it may dump a core file. If a user were to mishandle a core file, an attacker can reconstruct the user's wallet.dat file, including their private keys, via a grep "6231 0500" command.

I guess time needs to be spent resolving all the issues identified with the package.